# Twitter Badge destroyed my footer

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter, footer

In today's news, the official twitter widget (http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets) destroyed my footer completely. And I don't know why, since that script doesn't have access to my style.css

or does it?

I have tried to rearrange and ever redo the footer, and still the nice white space that the twitter widget created still persists. WTF is happening? Of all the tweaking I've done, the only thing that seems to work is deleting the entire footer. fantastic solution!

Can anybody help me?

footer.php:

```
</div> <!-- End of pagewrap -->

    <footer class="group">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="twittertitle"><h3>The Director's Production Diary @iampineros</h3>   </div>
        <div id="twitterbox"><div id="winfo"></div></div>

        <div id="sociallist">
            <ul>               
                <li><a href="#"><div id="facebooklogo"><h3>Facebook</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div id="twitterlogo"><h3>Twitter</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div id="flickrlogo"><h3>Flickr</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div id="vimeologo"><h3>Vimeo</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div id="youtubelogo"><h3>Youtube</h3></div></a></li>
            </ul>                                
        </div>
            <div id="disclaimer">All material published in this website is property of Filmliga unless stated otherwise. Please, don’t mess with us, thank you. Copyright 2011 FIlmliga/Benjamin Piñeros. All rights reserved. This site is powored by Wordpress.</div>

</footer>            

<?php wp_footer(); ?>


</body>

</html>
```

style.css:

```
#page-wrap { width:1020px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px; background: white; }

footer { width: 1020px; height: 300px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: #1e1e1e; }

#logo { width: 221px; height: 222px;position:relative; bottom: -20px; left: 20px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-image:url(images/logo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;  }

#twittertitle { position:relative; bottom: 208px; left: 270px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }

#twitterbox { position:relative; top: -203px; left: 270px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-image:url(images/twitterbox.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 540px; height: 190px; }

#winfo { position:relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background:none; width: 500px; height: 180px; }

#sociallist { position:relative; bottom: 393px; left: 837px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color:#282828; width: 140px; height: 190px; }

#sociallist ul { margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type:none; list-style-image:none; }

#sociallist li { margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }

#sociallist li h3:hover {color: #1ad4ff; }

#facebooklogo { background-position: center; background-image: url(images/facebooklogo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 26px; height: 26px; position:relative; top: 10px; left: 103px; }

#facebooklogo h3 { position:relative; bottom: 3px; right: 90px; }

#twitterlogo { background-position: center; background-image: url(images/twitterlogo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 33px; height: 25px; position:relative; top: 20px; left: 98px; }

#twitterlogo h3 { position:relative; bottom: 3px; right: 85px; }

#flickrlogo { background-position: center; background-image: url(images/flickrlogo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 26px; height: 26px; position:relative; top: 30px; left: 103px; }

#flickrlogo h3 { position:relative; bottom: 2px; right: 90px; }

#vimeologo { background-position: center; background-image: url(images/vimeologo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 27px; height: 24px; position:relative; top: 40px; left: 101px; }

#vimeologo h3 { position:relative; bottom: 2px; right: 87px; }

#youtubelogo { background-position: center; background-image: url(images/youtubelogo.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 24px; height: 29px; position:relative; top: 50px; left: 104px; }

#youtubelogo h3 { position:relative; bottom: 2px; right: 90px; }

#disclaimer { position: relative; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px 0px 0px 17px; text-align: left; font-size: 10px; word-spacing: 3px; }
```

Comment: Im not seeing the issue on your site, did you remove the button? Can you add it back to your page so I can see it, or be more specific on how its messing up your footer

Comment: Hello Josh how are you? Yes, I removed it. The problem is that UGLY white space it added between the black square of the footer and the disclaimer. You could put a planting field in there! That white space didn't exist prior to inserting the twitter widget.

Comment: That white space below my footer is the doing of the twitter widget. And although I removed the widget, the white space persists. That is not part of my code. That white space is not a part of my footer. How do I remove it?

Comment: Why do you have `<link>` elements outside the `<head>`?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not showing the <head> tag here.

Comment: No, but you put the address of your site, where there are `<link>` elements outside the `<head>`. I mention it because it's stopping your page from validating, so I figured it might be something you would want to look at.

Comment: Oh ok! Didn't know that. I'll check it up. Thank yo man. How did you notice?

Comment: ...and hey, just checked you site and it's fabulous. Minimal, functional. elegant.

Comment: @Benjamin 1) I ran your page through http://validator.w3.org -- this is a good way of checking for basic problems with a page, so I often do it when people have strange HTML problems. 2) Thanks :) Though the design's not mine, it's the Minimal Portfolio WordPress theme by [Cudazi](http://themeforest.net/user/cudazi/portfolio) on ThemeForest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're positioning things in a pretty strange way inside your footer... you're specifying lots of `top`, `left`, and `bottom` values on elements that have `position: relative`—these elements are still causing things to lay out as if they are in the normal flow of the document (which accounts for the huge bottom gap you see), and then they're also shifted by your positioning values.

A much more common (and easier) approach is to give your footer (or `.group`) `position:relative` and then apply `position: absolute` to the children—that way the children will be absolutely positioned relative to the parent.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on it right now. I'll tell you how it goes.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfect."Kei" and you were right. The layout using "relative" was awful to manage. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies is your layout. Your extensive use of absolute/relative positioning is messing up subsequent div placements. Consider redoing your layout.

Here's a quick fix though:
Apply to #disclaimer:

```
margin-top: -330px;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the perfect temporal fix. You are right, I have to redo the footer.

Comment: I have just finished redoing the footer with absolute parameters. And it works perfectly. Thank you very much!